# Which serial interface to choose from when working with sensors?

Tags: i2c, spi, sensors

From what I've seen with for example, the Adafruit L3GD20H Triple-Axis Gyro and Embeddio SNAP Board, both I2C and SPI serial interfaces are available by changing the SMD jumper positions.

Since the L3GD20H may be accessed through both the I2C and SPI serial interfaces, I would like to know what the advantages are of using one over another?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the main differences between SPI and I2C are:

- SPI generally supports higher bitrates.
- SPI can optionally support full duplex communication.
- I2C requires fewer signal lines.
- I2C has better support for connecting multiple devices on the same serial bus.
- SPI is in general a slightly simpler protocol than I2C.

Comment: I2C has a lot of issues on electrical level. See how many Q&A over Internet about capacitance and pull up resistors, length of wires, etc. On top of that, one need to put proper timings into the account. I would avoid I2C as much as possible. I2C is good only for the end product made on the pipeline where you have one configuration on PCB.